# What should be the output of the code below?

Tags: java, regex

In the below code the pattern does not have comma(,), whereas the string matched with it contains comma(,). Hence ideally the output of the code should be "Not Matches". But I am getting the output "Matches". Why the regex is accepting comma(,)?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String expression="Emplogin,,,,434pmc,";
    if(expression!=null){
        Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z0-9'\"-.:\\*?@/\\\\!_#$%&()\\[\\]{}=+\\p{Space}]+");
    Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(expression);
    if (m1.matches()){
    System.out.println("Matches");
    }else{
    System.out.println("Not Matches");
         }

         }

    }
```

Comment: Everything between `[` and `]` will be matched, no order here.

Comment: put `-` inside the char class at the first or at the last or escape it. So that it won't acts like a range operator.

Comment: * and ? are regex wildcards. so, might just as well be a comma

Comment: @Stultuske Inside a char class they loose their special meaning.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I did not get you. can you rewrite the regex please?

Comment: @Shahid How about you run the code yourself ? Do you know what is the meaning of your regex ? Try http://regex101.com

Comment: @MarounMaroun : The point is if you try to match the string "Emplogin,==<<<<<,,,434pmc,", the code output will be "Not Matches", as '<' is not there in the regex; but despite the regex does not contain ',' it matches a string that have ',' as substring.

Comment: @Shahid see the link i pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

The minus sign is a special char (means range from quote to point). escape it and your regexp should work.

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z0-9'\"\\-.:\\*?@/\\\\!_#$%&()\\[\\]{}=+\\p{Space}]+");
```